# I need help making a lightbox with a flash game embedded inside it

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I am making a games website and I have little knowledge in computer language and I need to create a lightbox that will appear when a image is click linking to this box. The box doesn't need to be too fancy or anything, all i need is for it to have an embedded flash games at a set size without scrolling. I have had a look at jquery and mootools but I find them confusing and don't know how to embed a flash based game inside them, so any help would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

[PrettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#prettyPhoto) jQuery makes it easy to lightbox media such as Flash.

From [their example](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#prettyPhoto):

```
<a title="Flash 10 demo" href="http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/include/marquee/design.swf?width=792&amp;height=294" rel="prettyPhoto[mixed]">
    <img src="/wp-content/themes/NMFE/images/thumbnails/flash-logo.jpg" alt="Flash 10 demo" width="50"/>
</a>
```

Put a link to the SWF with `rel=prettyPhoto[groupName]` in your anchor.

Within the anchor, you may place an image thumbnail.

```
<a href="flash.swf" rel="prettyPhoto[group]">
    <img src="thumbnail.png" />
</a>
```

[Download source](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/demos/prettyPhoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/prettyPhoto_compressed_3.1.4.zip).

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution that I think might be good looking would be having a container that's hidden from start. When you click at the image this container turns visible. This way you don't have to embed flash to jquery/javascript but to html.

With jquery it would look like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#yourimage').click(function(){
         $('#containerwithgame').show();
    });

});
```

This way you don't use an annoying pop-up lightbox, but that's a personal opinion.